# for loop+structure allocation in matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, data-structures

This is a  problem I am working on in Matlab.

I am looping through a series of *.ALL files and stripping the field name by a delimiter '.'. The first field is the network, second station name, third location code and fourth component. I pre-allocate my structure based on the number of files (3) I run through which for this example is a 3x3x3 structure that I would like to define as struct(station,loc code,component). You can see these definitions in my code example below.

I would like to loop through the station, loc code, and component and fill their values in the structure. The only problem is for some reason the way I've defined the loop it's actually looping through the files more than once. I only want to loop through each file once and extract the station, comp, and loc code from it and put it inside the structure. Because it's looping through the files more than once it's taken like 10 minutes to fill the structure. This is not very efficient at all. Can someone point out the culprit line for me or tell me what I'm doing incorrectly?

Here's my code below:

```
     close all;
     clear;
     [files]=dir('*.ALL');

     for i = 1:length(files) 
         fields=textscan(files(i).name, '%s', 'Delimiter', '.');
         net{i,1}=fields{1}{:};
         sta{i,1}=fields{1}{2};
         loc{i,1}=fields{1}{3};
         comp{i,1}=fields{1}{4};
         data = [];
         halfhour(1:2) = struct('data',data);
         hour(1:24) = struct('halfhour',halfhour);
         day(1:366) = struct('hour',hour);
         PSD_YE_DBT(1:length(files),1:length(files),1:length(files)) =     
         struct('sta','','loc','','comp','','allData',[],'day',day);
     end
     for s=1:1:length(sta)
        for l=1:1:length(loc)
          for c=1:1:length(comp)
             tempFileName = strcat(net{s},'.',sta{s},'.',loc{l},'.',comp{c},'.','ALL');
             fid = fopen(tempFileName);
             PSD_YE_DBT(s,l,c).sta = sta{s};
             PSD_YE_DBT(s,l,c).loc = loc{l};
             PSD_YE_DBT(s,l,c).comp = comp{c};
          end
         end
        end
```

Example file names for the three files I'm working with are:

```
XO.GRUT.--.HHE.ALL 
XO.GRUT.--.HHN.ALL 
XO.GRUT.--.HHZ.ALL
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try to `profile` your code. The bottleneck can very well be the I/O which leaves less options for optimization.

Comment: @Oleg Komarov: What do you mean by profile the code?

Comment: Explore the following guide: [Profiling for Improving Performance](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html)